# I keep getting a segmentation fault and I can't find it! I think ive narrowed it down to a particular function

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation

I say that it must be this function because it stops right after I enter an int and it doesn't read the print statement.

```
recipe** readAllRecipes(int numRecipes)
 {
   recipe** theRecipes = malloc(sizeof(recipe *) * numRecipes);
   int i;

   for(i = 0; i < numRecipes; i++)
   {
    scanf("%d", &theRecipes[i]->numItems);
    
    printf("\n\n\t\t here in readAll for loop\n");
    
    theRecipes[i] = readRecipe(theRecipes[i]->numItems);
   }

   return theRecipes;
}
```

Comment: `&theRecipes[i]->numItems` That is accessing invalid memory. `theRecipes` has been allocated some memory but not the individual `theRecipes[i]` entries.

Comment: @kaylum oh ok do i need to malloc memory for ```theRecipes[i]->numItems``` or ```theRecipes[i]``` in the for loop... idk i just thought that ```malloc(sizeof(recipe *) * numRecipes)``` would be sufficient. i dont really understand :c

Comment: It might be the order of operations in the second argument of the scanf call, try adding parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
        scanf("%d", &theRecipes[i]->numItems);
```

`theRecipise[i]` is not initalized and you dereference it. Should allocate it first:

```
        theRecipes[i] = malloc(sizeof(recipe));
        scanf("%d", &theRecipes[i]->numItems);
```

but lower down I'm baffled by this:

```
    theRecipes[i] = readRecipe(theRecipes[i]->numItems);
```